# Make a HTML Table have items be square based on the screen size using CSS?

Tags: html, css, electron

I'm currently making an electron app that requires a square grid of items (Sudoku). I've found solutions online for making the elements square, but that's based on width. And often times the width is going to be almost twice as big as the height, so based on that the grid items would go off the screen and I would not like that. I tried using

```
td{
height:11.11%;
padding-left:11.11%;
}
```

but it doesn't produce a square at all, in fact, the height becomes static at the minimum height if I do that. My question is how can I create a table that maintains square items based on height using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `vh` (viewport height) units. `1vh` is 1% of the height of the viewport.

Edit: add code example.

```css
td {
  height: 33vh;
  width: 33vh;
}
```

Comment: That works for having a dynamic height scaling, but now how do I make the width the same as the height, thus maintaining a square shape?

Comment: @user1979117 Use the width property. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Ah I see, you can access the height from the width, unlike the percentage values. Thanks! I'm marking this as the answer because this answers the question, but I'm probably going to look into CSS Grids in the future for this project.

Comment: CSS grid is great. Flexbox too. Tables are typically only used for showing tabular data (think stuff you'd find on a spreadsheet) these days, but they used to be the best tool we had for layouts more complicated than a single column.

Answer (score 1):

A table might not be a good idea for a sudoku grid. Tables have some limitations, especially with sizing. It's easier to build it with divs and a simple nested css grid.

Here's a fiddle for a rough idea: https://jsfiddle.net/Treverix/docy76gw/5/

The CSS looks like this:

```
.sudoku {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  gap: 0 0;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 384px;
}

.sudoku-square {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 126px;
  height: 126px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, auto);
  gap: 0 0;
}

.sudoku-cell {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks for the suggestion. I haven't used CSS Grids before but I'll definitely check them out.

Answer (score 0):

td is table-cell object, the width will change because table width.

so i edit its, now is square. see below

```css
*{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    table{
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse; 
    }
    td {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20%;
      padding-bottom: 20%;
      /*
      width: calc(20% - 2px);
      padding-bottom: calc(20% - 2px);
      background-color: #ff0000; 
      border: 1px solid #000; 
      */
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even){
      background-color: #0ff;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){
      background-color: #ff0;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd){
      background-color: #0ff;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even){
      background-color: #ff0;
    }
```

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```